# Why does the hosts file on my win 08 server only ressolves DNS queries for internal DNS names and not external?

Tags: domain-name-system

I added the following to my hosts file:

```
[Server IP] abc.local
[Server IP] abc.local
```

Only works when I query internally. externally I can the IP but the mapped name does reply when I ping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PING uses DNS resolution (when using server or domain names) to test network connectivity. The hosts file holds DNS records so when you query them (locally) you don't use the IP addresses but the domain names. So if you don't get a reply is because the server is not available or there's a problem with IP-domain name mapping. If you provide more details or need more clarification/help in something else, let us know.

Comment: I binded my site in IIS to abc.local and I added a mapping to my hosts file. Locally when I query abc.local I get a response and the web page loads but externally I get an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED exception. I can access the Default site in IIS externally by querying [SERVER].[DOMAIN] from the browser. By external I mean from my local machine within the domain (Intranet). Do you need more details?

Comment: So you are saying I should uses [server].[domain name] in my hosts file? i.e. [server].[domain name] abc.local

Comment: That didn't work for me :(.

Comment: Hosts file resolution only works where the file lives, beyond it won't work. So if you need domain name resolution from different machine locations then you'd need to configure a DNS server (or replicate the hosts file records across the machines).

Comment: So add the (IIS Server) IP address-abc.local mapping to the intranet machine hosts file (where you're testing) and that should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. If there is a DNS server somewhere in my institution's domain and I add a DNS role to the server I am using. Will this cause issues? Originally I want to add the DNS role and configure the DNS Server to use forwarders.

Comment: The server I am using is connected to the domain. My goal is to maintain domain names with out having to go through my Systems Team department.

Comment: If there's already a DNS server in your company and you implement one on your own it can pose a DNS record conflict so be aware of that. You can leverage the hosts file for development/testing purposes. (Don't forget to upvote or mark as an answer if this post was useful).